# Like button does not stay "clicked"

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, confirm

Facebook like button on my blog pages (e.g., http://maxltv.tumblr.com/post/43695254623/management-olympics) in most cases un-clicks after being clicked, and nothing gets posted after that. It looks as if the button stays presses for a second and then comes back up with nothing happening.

After a few attempts, the button brings in "Confirm" message. After clicking on "Confirm" the "Post" button in the confirmation pop-up behaves the same way - un-clicks itself within a second after being clicked.

this is really infuriating :-)

Comment: I think you have used some custom Social sharing plugin which may have any errors. You can remove FB like from the plugin and you can start using the Social plugin from FB itself. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Answer (score 0):

- Go to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/
- In the Input URL paste your page URL where the like button is not working
- Click the Lint button.

now you can go and visit your page to try the Like button.

if you have any queries update the question or add comments.

Comment: The provided link redirects to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug which has no Lint button.  The debug shows that a couple of og tags are missing, but that is usually not an issue.

Comment: It might be a silly question but have you checked in issue mobile browsers?